# how can I build the mysql bind_param() in a group of selects dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to generate differents sql SELECT statements for each different possible outcome. My question is how can I build the $stmt->bind_param() and how to output the result? Thanks

```
      $tipoCategorias = array(
          1 => 'ID_CAMARAS,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,MEGAPIXELES_CAMARAS,ZOOM_DIGITAL_CAMARAS FROM CAMARAS',
          2 => 'ID_CONSOLAS,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,COLOR_CONSOLAS FROM CONSOLAS', 
          3 => 'ID_JOYAS,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,TIPO_JOYAS,MATERIAL_JOYAS FROM JOYAS', 
          4 => 'ID_MOVILES,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,ID_OPERADOR,MEMORIA_MOVILES,IMEI_MOVILES,COLOR_MOVILES FROM MOVILES', 
          5 => 'ID_ORDENADORES,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,PROCESADOR_PORTATILES,MEMORIA_PORTATILES,HD_PORTATILES,PULGADAS_PORTATILES FROM PORTATILES', 
          6 => 'ID_TABLETS,ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS,ID_CATEGORIA,MEMORIA_TABLETS,COLOR_TABLETS FROM TABLETS');
      foreach($tipoCategorias as $keycampos => $valuecampos){
          if($keycampos==$id_categoria){

              $cSQL="SELECT " . $valuecampos . " WHERE ID_CATEGORIA=? AND ID_PRODUCTOS_OFERTADOS=?";
              $stmt=$oConni->prepare($cSQL);
              $stmt->bind_param('ii',$id_categoria,$id_prod_of);
              $stmt->execute();
              $stmt->store_result();
              /* here --> $stmt->bind_result(¿?); */
              $str=null;
              while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    /*$str.= Anything to output;*/

              }
              echo $str;
          }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) to call `$stmt->bind_param` with variable number of params. Also see [Callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) definition.

For binding result, you can use [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to the output variables the same way.

Example:

```
$params = array("iii", $a, $b, $c);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $params);

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$result = array(&$a, &$b);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_result"), $result);
```

Comment: How could I control or detect the number of output parameters?

Comment: You can just loop over the $params array and extract the data you need key => value.

Comment: @user2933000 I expanded the answer