# Update MYSQL row with non null value only

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a table contain huge number of rows and i need to update row with specific ID, for example assume i have a row with below details:

```
Id= 1
Name= lessa
Address = USA
```

now i used below PHP code to update the row:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","MyUserName","MyPassword","DB");
$id = '1';
$name = "";
$address = "UK";
// update only non value items
$r=mysqli_query($sql);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

now my issue since the value of address is changed from USA to UK i need to update this value only, also since the name value is nothing the name should be remain so after update the row should be like below:

```
ID=1
Name = lessa
Address = UK
```

Also if in another time the name value changed and address remain the same i need to update the name only.

also assume i have 100 column not only three as this example.

any help for write the update statement will be appreciated.

Update:

I use below code but no update happen:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(DB info);
$id = 'jo_12';
$name = "";
$address = "UK";
$sql = "UPDATE info
        SET name = IF(? = '', name, ?),
            address = IF(? = '', address, ?)
        WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $name, $name, $address, $address, $id);
$stmt->execute();

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Firstly, `mysql_error()` that doesn't mix with any other API than `mysql_`. Edit: So you've changed it, ok. Now, you also need to pass DB connection to your query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Read up on UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: You can make an array where the fieldnames are the keys and the values are the values, and then loop through the array and build the SQL with the ? and use PDO's execute function to pass in the array and prepare and execute at once.  Doing this with MySQLi is not as easy since you have to list out all the fields separately in `bind_param` rather than pass in an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974120/how-can-i-build-the-mysql-bind-param-in-a-group-of-selects-dynamically?s=1|1.0173 shows how to build a prepared query dynamically with mysqli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put tests in the `UPDATE` query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE yourTable
        SET name = IF(? = '', name, ?),
            address = IF(? = '', address, ?)
        WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die ($con->error);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $name, $address, $address, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

The `IF()` tests assign the old value of the column back to it if the variable is empty.

Comment: thank you sir, but could you explain what this statement name = IF(? = '', name, ?) will do ? and whats the mean of it's parameters ?

Comment: You need to read the mysqli documentation on prepared statements. The `?` placeholders are replaced with the corresponding variables from `bind_param()`.

Comment: after i apply it no any update happen:
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect(Myinfohere);

$id = 'jo_12';
$name = "";
$address = "UK";
$sql = "UPDATE info
        SET name = IF(? = '', name, ?),
            address = IF(? = '', address, ?)
        WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $name, $name, $address, $address, $id);
$stmt->execute();

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments, there's no formatting and it's hard to read.

Comment: If `id` is a string, not a number, use `sssss` instead of `ssssi`.

Comment: Are there any errors? I just added a modification to report an error coming from `$con->prepare()`.

Comment: no any error appear since i execute the php code from browser :( please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this SQL query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET Address='UK' WHERE ID=1
```

You can of course substitute ID=1 for any other number.

Comment: no but in the second time if the name changed and address still remain what i will do ? i need the update statement to discover the null value and not update it.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand your question. Do you want update only if some column is NULL?

Comment: @TomasPajurek He only wants to update the column if the corresponding variable is not null. So if `$name` is not empty, he wants to update the name with that.

Comment: @Barmar Yea, I got it now  and I consider your answer correct.